# Div size with relative content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div with some images inside:

```html
    <div>
        <img><img><img><img>
    <div>
```

The images would normally display in a row, however I have used some CSS to change their relative positions from left (-7px for the second one, -14px for the third, etc.) so they are stacked partially over each other. Is there a way to make the div to be only the width of the partially stacked images, rather than the width of where the images would be if they weren't moved?

Comment: Can you show your actual html along with the css? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the css as

```
div img {position: absolute;}
```

they will all overlap without needing any repositioning.
It will set the size of the img, and div to 0 so it will only work if there is nothing below it on the page.

Comment: This was the right approach, but as per my comment on Longblog's post, I am trying to center the content (forgot to mention that important detail), so it still centers the leftmost edge of the image set.

Comment: What are you trying to center them in relation to: the page, each other (meaning different size images with the centers matched up, or the div itself?

Answer (score 0):

If the content isn't dynamically generated then you can just manually set the div to the width you want using css.

```
<div class="overlap">
  <img><img><img>
</div>

.overlap {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I *think* I know what the content is, but there has to be a dynamic way to do this.  I want something that is modular and can be re-used easily.

Comment: Additionally, I meant to mention in the first post that I am trying to center these images after they are overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

To center the images try wrapping them in another div. Not sure what you have in all of your css but you can get the idea anyway. Something Like:

```
.overlap{
    width:200px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
.overlap img{
    outline:1px solid blue;
    display:block;
    height:50px; 
    width:25px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
.overlap img{
    left:-7px;
}   
.overlap img + img{
    left:-14px;
}   
.overlap img + img + img{
    left:-21px;
}
#center{
    width:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

<div class="overlap">
<div id="center">
    <img><img><img>
    </div>
</div>
```